# Get a value from string array by search id

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, substring

I have a list of values in an array **Cmnts** like

> "6_12_g2_text":"22","6_12_g3_text":"33","6_12_g4_text":"44"

```
var CmntsValue = forms["textvalue"];    
string[] Cmnts = CmntsValue.Split('{','}');
```

No I want to search for 6_12_g2_text and return 22 (for 6_12_g3_text and return 33). How can i achieve this?

---

I got the value as shown in following image!
[image: Json values]

I insert my updated code here [in second image]. Kindly check with that
[image: Not get all records properly]

Comment: You don't want an array, you want a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Comment: Is this a string or `List<string>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you have is actually a JSON string. Using [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can easily parse the string into a `Dictionary<string, int>`, like so:

```
var json = "{\"6_12_g2_text\":\"22\",\"6_12_g3_text\":\"33\",\"6_12_g4_text\":\"44\"}";
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);
```

And then extract any value by key:

```
int value;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("6_12_g2_text", out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

**Edit:**

After seeing your actual JSON string, you're going to have to do some additional work:

```
var json = "{\"1_3_g1_text\":\"11\"}
            {\"1_3_g2_text\":\"\"}
            {\"6_12_g2_text\":\"test\"}
            {\"6_12_g3_text\":\"\"}
            {\"1_17_g1_text\":\"works\"}
            {\"5_19_g2_text\":\"submitted\"}
            {\"5_19_g3_text\":\"2\"}";

var jsons = json.Split('{', '}').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
var concatenatedJson = string.Format("{{{0}}}", string.Join(",", jsons));

var intermidiateDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(
                                                                      concatenatedJson);
```

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Thank you. Now i can able to get value. But for null values i got the error :  "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '1_3_g1_text', line 1, position 17." How can i overcome this

Comment: @KaviSuja You have `null`s in your JSON?

Comment: ya.. the available values it has string,int,null,empty

Comment: Please post a full JSON string.

Comment: {"1_3_g1_text":"11"}{"1_3_g2_text":""}{"1_3_g3_text":""}
{"6_12_g1_text":""}{"6_12_g2_text":"test"}{"6_12_g3_text":""}
{"1_13_g1_text":""}{"1_13_g2_text":""}{"1_13_g3_text":""}
{"6_14_g1_text":""}{"6_14_g2_text":"34"}{"6_14_g3_text":""}
{"7_16_g1_text":""}{"7_16_g2_text":""}{"7_16_g3_text":""}
{"1_17_g1_text":"works"}{"1_17_g2_text":""}{"1_17_g3_text":""}
{"9_18_g1_text":""}{"9_18_g2_text":""}{"9_18_g3_text":""}
{"5_19_g1_text":""}{"5_19_g2_text":"submitted"}{"5_19_g3_text":"2"}

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov I attached the screenshot of actual values i got in my answer. Please check it

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I try with above one. I am not able to get values seperately. I update my code in second image. Kindly check it

Comment: @KaviSuja Your `FValue` is a string, yet the dictionary is a mapping from `string` to `int`. That code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83202/discussion-between-kavisuja-and-yuval-itzchakov).